# Read the file when it is created in Python

Tags: python, file

I writed app which get order details from prestashop database, put they to XML file, then UPS WorldShip (software for sending UPS parcels) import that XML file and create own out file with result as tracking number. In the next step I am parsing that exit file to get tracking number and save it in my local database.

My problem is how to get just created (.out) file only then when it is ready (created). At this moment I have code like this:

```
tree.write("C:/ProgramData/UPS/WSTD/IMPEXP/XML Auto Import/" + today + "-" + order_id + ".xml", encoding="utf-8", xml_declaration=True)
time.sleep(1)
out_file = etree.parse("C:/ProgramData/UPS/WSTD/IMPEXP/XML Auto Import/" + today + "-" + order_id + ".out")
```

And this is poor solution. I would like "wait until the file will be created".

I know in python is fonction `isfile()` which check does file exist, but I do not know how to check until it will in fact, there will be.

Comment: See [`watchdog`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/watchdog) for cross-platform, event-based monitoring of system events. Or just use an old-fashioned polling in a explicit loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution is to poll. Here I draw inspiration from Selenium's [WebDriverWait](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/py/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py#L26) class.

```
from time import time, sleep

class Waiter(object):
    def __init__(self, poll=0.5, timeout=60):
        self.poll = poll
        self.timeout = timeout

    def until(self, callable, message='Timed out'):
        end_time = time() + self.timeout

        while True:
            value = callable()
            if value:
                break

            sleep(self.poll)

            if time() > end_time:
                raise Exception(message)
```

To use the above class, just initialize it and pass a callable to its `until()` method.

```
import os
wait = Waiter()
wait.until(lambda: os.path.exists('fake.txt'))
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution could be keep checking the list of files in your output directory: when the list changes it means you added new files that you can process.

Pseudo code:

```
import os

checked_files = []

while(1):

   all_files = os.listdir(output_folder)
   new_files = set(all_files) - set(checked_files)

   for file in new_files:
       # Process them
       ....

   checked_files = all_files
```